# Analyzing the Compact fourth order difference involving $\left(1+\frac{h^{2}}{6} \delta^{2}\right)^{-1}$

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

Consider the implicit leapfrog scheme
$$
\frac{u_{m}^{n+1}-u_{m}^{n-1}}{2 k}+a\left(1+\frac{h^{2}}{6} \delta^{2}\right)^{-1} \delta_{0} u_{m}^{n}=f_{m}^{n}
$$
for the one-way wave equation
$$
u_{t}+a u_{x}=f .
$$
Here $\delta^{2}$ is the central second difference operator, and $\delta_{0}$ is the central first difference operator.

(1) show that the scheme is of order $(2,4)$.

(2) show that the scheme is stable if and only if $\left|\frac{a k}{h}\right|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.$$$$
This is a compact fourth order difference scheme. Since there's a $\left(1+\frac{h^{2}}{6} \delta^{2}\right)^{-1}$ term here, to deal with this, my idea is to take the operator $\left(1+\frac{h^{2}}{6} \delta^{2}\right)$ at both sides to cancel it. This is a very direct method, but it requires a lot of calculation, the scheme will become very long after the expansion. My question is, is there any other way to deal with such an $\left(1+\frac{h^{2}}{6} \delta^{2}\right)^{-1}$ operator which needs not that much computation? Thanks!

Comment: Taylor expand $(1+x)^{-1} = 1 - x +  x^2 - x^3 + \ldots$ ?

Comment: @G.Gare I don't much understand here, why can we Taylor expand this operator? What makes this action convincing?

Comment: just a suggestion, not an answer. maybe it doesn't work, I haven't tried. I thought that Taylor would make the second term look like $a\delta_0 u_m^n(1 - h^2\delta^2/6) + O(h^4\delta^4)$ which seems somehow easier to live with than what you have.

Comment: Implicit schemes do not usually have inverse operators. Could you please explain how you got that representation?

Comment: @G.Gare small correction, $(1 - h^2 \delta^2 / 6)$ is an operator, so it should appear on the left of $u^n_m$ which it is acting on. Also $O(h^4 \delta^4)$ should be $O(h^4 u^{IV})$

Comment: @uranix yes correct but the technique can be applied still